# Factorial and product form of gamma function

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function

Let $z\in\mathbb{C}$. We know that $$\dfrac{1}{\Gamma(z)}=e^{\gamma z}\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+\dfrac{z}{n}\right)e^{-z/n},$$ where $$\gamma=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N\dfrac1n-\log N.$$

How can we use this to prove that $$\Gamma(z)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{n^zn!}{z(z+1)\ldots(z+n)}?$$

Comment: Your last gamma must be a capital one, i.e.: the last limit is $\;\Gamma(z)\;$ , **not** $\;\gamma(z)\;$ . This is the gist in the Bohr-Mollerup Theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $\Gamma(z)$ as the limit of the partial products,

$$\begin{align}
\Gamma(z) &= \lim_{n\to \infty} e^{-\gamma z}\frac1z\prod_{k=1}^n \left(1+\frac{z}{k}\right)^{-1}e^{z/k}\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n!}{\prod_{k=0}^n (z+k)}\exp \left(z\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k - \gamma\right)\right)\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n! n^z}{z(z+1)\dotsb(z+n)}\exp\left(z\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k - \log n - \gamma\right)\right).
\end{align}$$

Since $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac1k - \log n - \gamma \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$, the second factor converges to $1$, hence

$$\Gamma(z) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n! n^z}{z(z+1)\dotsb (z+n)}.$$